# Different set of InfoPath form's Page View based on URL

Tags: infopath, forms-services

Is it possible that one can enter a URL in a web browser that point to a certain page view for a web-based InfoPath 2007 form? (For SharePoint Server 2007)

Scenario:
A web-based InfoPath form that have 2 views - Summary View and Detail View. A user can enter a URL (e.g. http://server/site/form?view=detail) to view the Detail view of the web-based InfoPath 2007 form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is no code solution for this issue. You can find some info on code solution here:

- [Passing Data into a Form: Input Parameters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/02/26/passing-data-into-a-form-input-parameters.aspx)

However you should check if some other condition exist (eg. username, status) witch you can then use to switch view on load.

Comment: Hi Vedran, may I ask if I upgrade to SharePoint 2010, will I get to have a "no code" solution?

Comment: Take a look at [How to Pass Querystring data into an InfoPath Form](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/06/03/how-to-pass-querystring-data-into-an-infopath-form.aspx)

Comment: I think it is really no solution for InfoPath 2007 but thanks for the solution for InfoPath 2010.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is: `newifs.aspx?DefaultView=YOURFORMVIEWNAME`

Comment: I don't know if this works for 2007, but it definitely works for 2010.